# User profile Pick a premade Design/theme

Tags: customization, buddypress, profiles

i currently have been working on a huge project for the last few months
and im not a big coder myself but i know a bit, so i needed help, i wanted to assign each user with a already premade design kinda like twitter has you preview the design/with icons and live preview/ were they can pick a few premade designs, if they desire it of course if possible but it seems i run into issue because my lack of skills ,
its kinda would be a custom design for each user ?…
its this possible or is there another alternative? like can i provide custom images/backgrounds,
they can pick as there background at least that..

i really hope someone can help me out thank you, have a nice day.!

Answer (score 1):

not really sure what your point, but you can use [**body class**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) to customize background images ( AFAIK twitter use this method too ).

for example if you have two user : x and y

you can customize the author page :

yoursite.com/author/x

yoursite.com/author/y

with css like these

.author-x {background:red}

.author-y {background:blue}

Comment: this is what i want to achieve http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/06/live-background-change-using-jquery.html